# divide by zero error

Tags: java, divide-by-zero

here is the code (java):

```
class prime
{

    public static boolean prime (int a, int b) 
    { 
        if (a == 0) 
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else if ((a%(b-1) == 0) && (b>2))
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else if (b>1) 
        {
            return (prime (a, b-1)) ;
        }
        else
        {
            return true; 
        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] arg) 
    {
        System.out.println (prime (7, 7)) ; 
    }
}
```

This is the error message i get when i try to run it (it compiles fine):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at prime.prime(prime.java:10)
    at prime.prime(prime.java:16)
    at prime.prime(prime.java:16)
    at prime.prime(prime.java:16)
    at prime.prime(prime.java:16)
    at prime.prime(prime.java:16)
    at prime.prime(prime.java:16)
    at prime.main(prime.java:27)
```

So this means i devided by zero some how right? or does it mean something else? I don't see how i'm dividing by zero. What went wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try turning this around

```
if ((a%(b-1) == 0) && (b>2))
```

to

```
   if ((b>2) && a%(b-1)==0)
```

What's happening is that the `a%(b-1)` operation is being executed before the `b>2` test.

After the switch, you are taking advantage of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Once the b>2 test returns false, then there's no need to calculate the modulus (hence avoiding the division)

Answer (score 2):

Because of your recursive call:

```
return (prime (a, b-1)) ;
```

You will at some point be calling prime with a value for b of 1. Which means on your second condition you will be testing `a%0`. Since the modulo operator (%) is essentially a divide, that is bringing your divide by zero issue.

The solution is probably to catch this case to enforce b > 2 in your condition before doing the %.

Answer (score 1):

```
 A % B = C
```

**The Mathematical meaning** of the `%` is that you divide `A` by `B` and the reminder of this operation is `C`. When `B` is `0`  you effectively ask : What is the reminder when we divide by zero ?. In mathematics though, division by zero is undefined and this is the reason for `java.lang.ArithmeticException`

Answer (score 0):

I assume any code of the form `x % 0` will throw this error. Your code does not guard against this possibility.